# Error while calling udf from within withColumn in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

I receive and error while calling udf from within withColumn in Spark using Scala.
This error happens while building with SBT.

```
val hiveRDD = sqlContext.sql("select * from iac_trinity.ctg_us_clickstream")
hiveRDD.persist()

val trnEventDf = hiveRDD
  .withColumn("system_generated_id", getAuthId(hiveRDD("session_user_id")))
  .withColumn("application_assigned_event_id", hiveRDD("event_event_id"))


val getAuthId = udf((session_user_id:String) => {
    if (session_user_id != None){
        if (session_user_id != "NULL"){
            if (session_user_id != "null"){
            session_user_id
          }else "-1"
        }else "-1"
    }else "-1"
  }
```

)

I receive the error which is -

```
scala:58: No TypeTag available for String
val getAuthId = udf((session_user_id:String) => {
```

It compiles properly when instead of (session_user_id:String) I use (session_user_id:Any) but fails in runtime as Any is not recognized in Spark.
Please let me know how to handle this.

Comment: Error or not this doesn't make sense. Object of class `String` cannot be `None`!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried being explicit with your types?

```
udf[String, String]((session_user_id:String)...
```

Comment: Yes , I have tried being explicit -
val getAuthId = udf[String,String]((session_user_id:String) => if (session_user_id == None) ....

the error is the same - 
scala:57: No TypeTag available for String
[error]   val getAuthId = udf[String,String]((session_user_id:String) => if (session_user_id == None)"-1"

Comment: @preitamojha are you sure you are executing the same code your are giving us ? It seems unlikely that this doesn't work. I can't reproduce the error.